# Kubuntu 16.04 launcher font unreadable

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde5

After updating from 15.10 to 16.04 I noticed this odd font issue only in the KDE launcher. I'm using proprietary nVidia drivers. Everything else in the OS seems to render correctly.

[image: screenshot]